# Get value from a JSON

Tags: json

I have a JSON that looks like this, it comes from a knockout array and has been converted. I simply want to content this to a single object to send to a service.

```
[{\"NotePadID\":-1,\"UserID\":\"NIGOV\\\\\\\\dard-lytts\",\"DateInput\":\"08/28/2014\",\"CategoryID\":6,\"SubCategoryName\":\"Active Farmer\",\"DateCreated\":\"08/28/2014\",\"Note\":\"test\"}]
```

This comes as an array how would I get the first, ie

```
  var test = jsonConverted[0]['CategoryID'];
```

Always returns undifined. What I actually want to do is just pass a single object to my ajax, should be simple but not working.

Comment: Please `console.log(jsonConverted)` and check if it's string or object

Comment: That's not JSON. You have rogue ``\`` characters in it.

Comment: You really should specify in your question (or at least in the tags) which programming language you want to use. I guess it's javascript but it could be anything really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using javascript you can do it like

```
var a = '[{\"NotePadID\":-1,\"UserID\":\"NIGOV\\\\\\\\dard-lytts\",\"DateInput\":\"08/28/2014\",\"CategoryID\":6,\"SubCategoryName\":\"Active Farmer\",\"DateCreated\":\"08/28/2014\",\"Note\":\"test\"}]'
return JSON.parse(a)[0]['CategoryID']
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this and follow the "Demo"

```
var stringiFiedArray = "[{\"NotePadID\":-1,\"UserID\":\"NIGOV\\\\\\\\dard-lytts\",\"DateInput\":\"08/28/2014\",\"CategoryID\":6,\"SubCategoryName\":\"Active Farmer\",\"DateCreated\":\"08/28/2014\",\"Note\":\"test\"}]";

var javasArrar = JSON.parse(stringiFiedArray);
alert(javasArrar[0]["CategoryID"]);
```

**you can click here to see [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gihandilanka/xxjr9o5p/)**